# ORACLE CODE TO GROUP DATA BASED ON MONTHS

Tags: sql

I have a table which has the dates in the format `yyyymmdd`. I want to extract a report based on month and on notification type.

[image: Below is the input]

The below is the expected output.

[image: Expected output]

Please let us know. How can this be achieved using SQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
 select to_number(substr(date, 5, 2)) month
 , notiftype
 , count(*)
 from yourTable
 group by to_number(substr(date, 5, 2)), notiftype
```

However, selecting a month without the year is rarely a good idea.